# Retrieving groups by their index. Are Pandas groups sorted?

Tags: python, pandas

Say I group a Pandas dataframe around some column

```
df.groupby(cols)
```

Are groups sorted according to any criteria?

One way to retrieve a group is:

```
ix = 0
grouped.get_group(grouped.groups.keys()[ix])
```

but it is a bit verbose, and it's not clear that `keys()` above will give the groups in order.

Another way:

```
df = df.set_index(col)
df.loc[idx[df.index.levels[0][0],:],:]
```

but again, that's really verbose.

Is there another way to get a group by its integer index?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`groupby` has a `sort` parameter which is `True` by default, thus the groups are sorted. As for getting the `n`th group, it looks like you'd have to define a function, and use an internal API:

```
In [123]: df = DataFrame({'a': [1,1,1,1,2,2,3,3,3,3], 'b': randn(10)})

In [124]: df
Out[124]:
   a       b
0  1  1.5665
1  1 -0.2558
2  1  0.0756
3  1 -0.2821
4  2  0.8670
5  2 -2.0043
6  3 -1.3393
7  3  0.3898
8  3 -0.3392
9  3  1.2198

[10 rows x 2 columns]

In [125]: gb = df.groupby('a')

In [126]: def nth_group(gb, n):
   .....:     keys = gb.grouper._get_group_keys()
   .....:     return gb.get_group(keys[n])
   .....:

In [127]: nth_group(gb, 0)
Out[127]:
   a       b
0  1  1.5665
1  1 -0.2558
2  1  0.0756
3  1 -0.2821

[4 rows x 2 columns]
```

Comment: Thanks @Philip. Is this interface still supported? The method `_get_group_keys` does not seem to be available anymore.

Answer (score 1):

How about:

```
key, df2 = iter(grouped).next()
```